# How to insert different <script> code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ads

How to show a different Ad for mobile, desktops and countries?
My script is checking width and checking country code.
after detect that, I need to show a different ad codes witch wrote not only 1 line and contain another tags

```
`<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script> <!-- responsive tags / functions.php--><ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:block" data-ad-client="ca-pub-111" data-ad-slot="111" data-ad-format="auto"></ins> <script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>`
```

How Can I do that?

For now I include all the ad and remove some after DOM loaded, but that's not the solution.

https://jsfiddle.net/wtpdbu7q/

Comment: I can do that by server side (php) but it will very depends on IP check location service.

Comment: How to append script with ;  <  >  " and etc symbols with no conflict ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you can use `$(window).width()`

```
if ( $(window).width() > 767) {     
  // Add your javascript for desktop
  $('head').append('<script src=\"desktop.js\" type="text/javascript\"><\/script>');
}
else {
  // Add your javascript for tablet / mobile
  $('head').append('<script src=\"mobile.js\" type="text/javascript\"><\/script>');
}
```

Comment: the question how to write so big ad code by jquery or javascript